# Regex to delete HTML within <table> tags

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have an HTML document in `.txt` format containing multiple tables and other texts and I am trying to delete any HTML (anything within "`<>`") if it's inside a table (between `<table>` and `</table>`). For example:

```
===================
other text
<other HTML>
<table>
<b><u><i>bold underlined italic text</b></u></i>
</table>
other text
<other HTML>
==============
```

The final output would be as the following. Note that only HTML within  and  are removed.

```
==============
other text
<other HTML>
<table>
bold underlined italic text        
</table>
other text
<other HTML>
=============
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think parts of your question have disappeared due to HTML-tag parsing of your text. Try putting the tags in single ticks (\`), like so: `<html>`

Comment: For starters: [Don't parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Using regexes for this would involve a bunch of assumptions. You can run into problems if, for example, you assume that anything between `<` and `>` is a tag, even if it's not valid HTML. So a mathematical expression like `x<y and z>2` could cause problems. *If* you can state a bunch of assumptions we can follow, then someone can likely provide a satisfactory regex. But it's probably better not to use regexes at all as zzzzBov suggests.

Answer (score 4):

### Use the HTMLDocument Class Instead of Regex

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument
Imports System.IO.File

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myHTMLString As String

        Dim myDoc As HtmlDocument
        Dim myTables As HtmlElementCollection
        Dim myTable As HtmlElement

        Dim myAllTags As HtmlElementCollection
        Dim myHTMLTag As HtmlElement

        myHTMLString = ReadAllText("C:\Users\Geoffrey Van Wyk\Desktop\myPage1.txt")
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = myHTMLString

        myDoc = WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(True)
        myDoc.Write(myHTMLString)

        myTables = myDoc.GetElementsByTagName("table")
        myTable = myTables.Item(0)

        For Each child As HtmlElement In myTable.Children
            child.OuterText = child.InnerText
        Next

        myAllTags = myDoc.GetElementsByTagName("html")
        myHTMLTag = myAllTags.Item(0)

        WriteAllText("C:\Users\Geoffrey Van Wyk\Desktop\myPage2.txt", myHTMLTag.OuterHtml)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tested it. It works.

Answer (score 2):

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"<table>(.|\n)*?</table>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Here input is the string that contains html. This regex will remove all the tags and text that are between start table and  end /table tag. Try it !!!