# Remove HTML with Regex

Tags: asp.net, html, regex

Is it possible to use regex to remove HTML tags inside a particular block of HTML?

E.g.

```
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
          <p>My First HTML Table</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to remove all P tags, only those within the table element.

The ability to both remove or retain the text inside the nested p tag would be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: Inside a particular block of HTML? Sure. `s[<p>My First HTML Table</p>][My First HTML Table]` — but for any general solution, use a real HTML parser.

Comment: I must refer you to the canonical answer to any question involving HTML and regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Andrew - certainly my favourite answer ever - and I guess THE favourite answer on all of SE :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of mentions regarding *not to use regex when parsing HTML*, so you could use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) for this:

```
var html = @"
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
          <p>My First HTML Table</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";

HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//p");
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(
        HtmlNode.CreateNode(node.InnerHtml),
        node
    );
}

string result = null;
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    document.Save(writer);
    result = writer.ToString();
}
```

So after all these manupulations, you'll get the next `result`:

```
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
          My First HTML Table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>[\r\n\s]*<p>([^<]*)</p>[\r\n\s]*</td>
```

The round brackets denote a numbered capture group which will contain your text.

However, using regular expressions in this way relies on a lot of assumptions regarding the content of the `<p>` tag and the construction of the HTML.

Have a read of the ubiquitous SO question regarding [using regular expressions to parse (X)HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and see @Bruno's answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this link in which it seems the exact question was asked

"I have an HTML document in .txt format containing multiple tables and other texts and I am trying to delete any HTML (anything within "<>") if it's inside a table (between  and ). For example:"

[Regex to delete HTML within <table> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502325/regex-to-delete-html-within-table-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Possible to some extent but not reliable!

I will rather suggest you to look at HTML parsers such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).